# What is apt-cache used for?

Tags: command-line

Can anyone please define what exactly the APT cache is?

Comment: [`apt-cache`'s manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html), maybe this can help out a bit, while waiting for someone to give you a better answer?

Comment: Are you referring to the terminal command 'apt-cache'?

Comment: The heading says `apt-cache` and not "APT cache", then also there's the `command-line` tag and also the only question to date which describes the command is almost as much upvoted as the question, so I must suppose the question refers to the command. But what is the "APT cache" used for? That's a very legit question. I asked it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321028/whats-the-point-of-keeping-packages-in-apt-cache).

Answer (score 19):

`apt-cache` is a command to manipulate and obtain information from the packages at apt's cache.

It creates a repository of information about the packages that are avaiable from your sources list, so this way you can search packages and information about it.

Let's say you want to install a chat program but you don't know the name of a package for it.

You would open a console and type:

`sudo apt-cache search chat`

This would return a list of packages available and that refer to the word **chat**.

## Typical operations with `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache add
```

Adds a package file to the source cache.

```
apt-cache gencaches
```

Builds both the package and source cache

```
apt-cache showpkg
```

Show some general information for a single package

```
apt-cache stats
```

Show some basic statistics

```
apt-cache dump
```

Show the entire file in a terse form

```
apt-cache dumpavail
```

Print an available file to stdout

```
apt-cache unmet
```

Show unmet dependencies

```
apt-cache check
```

Check the cache a bit

```
apt-cache search
```

Search the package list for a regex pattern

```
apt-cache show
```

Show a readable record for the package

```
apt-cache depends
```

Show raw dependency information for a package

```
apt-cache pkgnames
```

List the names of all packages

```
apt-cache dotty
```

Generate package graphs for GraphVis

Don't forget to add package name after the commands listed above.

[Source1](http://www.ccl.net/cca/software/UNIX/updating-redhat/apt-howto/how-to-use-apt-cache.html)

**[Source2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)**