# How to get list of installable packages from repositories?

Tags: package-management, repository

I wanted to install a few packages but had to power down my laptop as I had a few chores to do. I did add the packages' repositories and forgot to install the packages. As my browser history clears on closing, I couldn't recall their names (I'm bad at names).

I would like to know if there is any way I can inquire all available packages (i.e. which I can download or have downloaded) using my repositories?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command line way of obtaining such a list would be **[apt-cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180996/what-is-apt-cache-used-for)**:

```
apt-cache dump # short list
apt-cache dumpavail # long list
```

This will take some time due to the many packages available.

You can `grep` `Package:` by following command:

```
apt-cache dumpavail | grep "Package:"
```

My personal approach to view packages I can't remember still is installing and running [Synaptic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic) [image: Install synaptic] which has a searchable GUI and can also be used to install and purge a given package.

Comment: Synaptic works some what the way I want.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do it without messing with system configuration :

Target architectures for repositories are available in the `InRealease` file.

This is especially useful because with some repository management software, you cannot have http access to the repo.

Example with rabbitmq repo

```
deb https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/debian/ stretch main
```

First, get `InRelease` file :

```
wget https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease
```

Once you've located what you want in that file (target arch), do the following :

```
wget -q -O- https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages | grep -E 'Package|Version'
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's in the official repository, you can search or browse all available packages via web: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

All packages for Ubuntu 12.10:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/allpackages

Of course you can run `apt-get update` and `apt-cache search keyword` to search for packages if you remember anything related.

If it's a PPA or 3rd party, you'd better check the repo's URL and see the list. For example, Cassandra:

http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian/dists/11x/main/binary-amd64/

http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian/pool/main/c/cassandra/

Answer (score 0):

if you run or add in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

then you can use name autocompletion for packages the same way as for commands in Bash.

For example: apt-get i first_couple_of_letters_of_package

hitting TAB wil propose the available choices