# what does apt-cache depends packagename?

Tags: apt, dependencies

does the command apt-cache depends package_name list out the level 1 dependencies of the package or all the dependencies of the package recursively? The answer in 
[What is apt-cache used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180996/what-is-apt-cache-used-for)
says that it displays raw dependencies. Is it same as level1 dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-cache depends` is not recursive. There's a separate tool called `apt-rdepends` for that. I have no idea what you mean by "level 1" dependencies, I have not seen that term in any official packaging documentation.

Comment: By level 1 dependencies, I mean the first level of dependencies for a package. For example, A is a package and it's dependencies are B and C. However, in turn B depends on D and E , and C depends on F. In this case, B and C are first level dependencies.

Comment: Since `apt-cache depends` is not recursive, yes, that's mostly what it means.