# Difference between apt-get and apt-cache

Tags: command-line, apt, apt-cache

Being a new comer in Ubuntu environment, I am bit confused between the apt-get and apt-cache. Can anyone explain what is difference between apt-get and apt-cache. And when to use the apt-get and apt-cache?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Related: [What is apt-cache used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180996/what-is-apt-cache-used-for)

Comment: Thanks @karel I will delete the post

Comment: `apt-get` will download (get) & install/remove packages & dependencies etc to your system.  `apt-cache` will do none of that, but is used to do searches and the like using the cached database of packages on your system (ie. display meta data, detail about packages without any installation/removing/changes etc)

Comment: @Melbius  Clicked that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-cache` is for queries, i.e. for searching packages and getting details like dependencies or versions.

`apt-get` is for, well getting it, installing, package management in general.

The tasks of `apt-get` and `apt-cache` are nowadays handled by `apt` (via e.g. `apt install` and `apt search`).

Check them `man` entries of either for more details.